# Is there any way to Load mibs file and to translate OIDs in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, snmp-trap

NiFi, is there any way to load mib files and translate the SNMPTraps according to them.

here is sample OIDs, wants to translate in prescribed mib structure

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.1031.1.1.1.5.1.4.25.47.67.80.85.47.67.80.85.47.67.80.85.67.112.117.85.116.105.108.47.118.97.108.117.101
```

Answer (score 0):

MIBs are in ASN.1 format right? If so, NiFi has an ASN1 Reader but it is not included in the convenience binary. You'd want to match the version of your NiFi and download something like https://repository.apache.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/org/apache/nifi/nifi-asn1-nar/1.24.0/nifi-asn1-nar-1.24.0.nar (which is for Apache NiFi 1.24.0, the latest at the time of this writing). Once copying that to your NiFi's `lib/` directory and restarting, you can read its documentation and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: nice to hear this, will visit this and see how we can leverage this.